# How to remove # from url in vue.js app while using cdn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

While building vue.js app using cli and vue-router, we can pass in `mode: 'history'` to router and that will remove hash from url. But how to remove # from url when using vue through cdn, for example in [todoMVC app](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/blob/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-todomvc/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import `vue-router` from cdn also, and connect it to Vue

Example is given in official docs

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript